# JSP how to link between 2 java classes to add items to arraylist and display them in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, hyperlink

Heyy I'm new to JSP and would like to know how to solve a small problem. I'm not sure how to do the link between the Client.java and Item.java to be able to add new items into the ArrayList and display it on the jsp page.

This is my Client.java code:
    package javaCode;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Client {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int phone;
    private String address;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    public ArrayList<Item> list;
    private String shipping;
    private int fee;
    private double discount;
    private Item item;


    public Client() {
     list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
     return name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
     this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
     return email;
    }

    public void setPhone(int phone) {
     this.phone = phone;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
     return phone;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
     this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
     return address;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
     this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
     return country;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
     this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity() {
     return city;
    }

    public void setShipping(String shipping) {
     this.shipping = shipping;
    }

    public String getShipping() {
     return shipping;
    }

    public void setFee() {
     if(this.shipping == "") {
        this.fee = 0;
     }
     if(this.shipping == "USPS Express Mail") {
        this.fee = 200;
     }
     if(this.shipping == "USPS Priority Mail") {
        this.fee = 300;
     }
     if(this.shipping == "DHL") {
        this.fee = 400;
     }
     if(this.shipping == "FedEx") {
        this.fee = 50;
     }
    }

    public int getFee() {
     return fee;
    } 

    public void setDiscount(double discount) {
     this.discount = discount;
    }

    public double getDiscount() {
     return discount;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
     list.add(this.item);
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getList() {
     return list;
    }
}
```

This is my Item code:
     package javaCode;

```
 public class Item {
  private String item;
  private int quantity;
  private double price;

  public Item() {
  }

  public void setItem(String item) {
    this.item = item;
  }

  public String getItem() {
    return item;
  }

  public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    //Client.list.add(this);
  }

  public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
  }

  public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public double getTotal() {
    return (quantity*price);
  }
}
```

This is the clientdetails.jsp file:

```
<jsp:useBean id="iteminfo" class="javaCode.Item"/> 
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="iteminfo"/> 
<jsp:useBean id="userinfo" class="javaCode.Client" scope="request"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="userinfo"/> 
<h2>Personal Information</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="name" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>E-mail</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="email" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="phone" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="address" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="country" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="city" name="userinfo" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Shipping Method</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="shipping" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Shipping Amount</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="fee" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Discount</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="discount" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>List</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="list" name="userinfo"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Item1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="quantity" name="iteminfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Unit Price</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="price" name="iteminfo"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="total" name="iteminfo"/></td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

This is the form.jsp file (containing html form):

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formstyle4.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="order" id="orderForm" action="clientdetails.jsp"   method="post">
        <p id="date"><script type="text/javascript"></script></p>
        <h2>Personal Information</h2>
        <label id="fname">* Name</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeypress="return !isNumber(event)" required>
        <label id="labemail">E-mail</label><input type ="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail(this)" required><br/><br/>
        <label for="address" id="labaddr">* Address</label>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="25" id="address" name="address" required></textarea>
        <label id="labcountry">Country</label>
        <select id="country" name="country">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
            <option value="UAE">UAE</option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
        </select><br/><br/>
        <label id="labphone">* Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onblur="validPhone()" required>
        <label id="labcity">City</label><input type="text" name="city" id="city" onkeypress="return !isNumber(event)" required><br><br>
        <br><br>
        <table id="orderTable">
            <th colspan="4">Order Details</th>
            <tr id="first">
                <td>Item</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Unit Price</td>
                <td>Total</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="item">Item1</td>
                <td><input onblur="findTotal(1)" class="item" type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></td>
                <td><input onblur="findTotal(1)" class="item" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" name="price" id="price" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></td>
                <td><input onblur="totals()" class="item" type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly></td>
            </tr>
            <!--
            <tr>
                <td id="item">Item2</td>
                <td><input onblur="findTotal(2)" type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></td>
                <td><input onblur="findTotal(2)" type="text" name="price" id="price" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></td>
                <td><input onblur="totals()" type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="item3">Item3</td>
                <td><input onblur="findTotal(3)" type="text" name="val3" id="qt3" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></td>
                <td><input onblur="findTotal(3)" type="text" name="val3" id="price3" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></td>
                <td><input onblur ="totals()" type="text" name="total" id="total3" readonly></td>
            </tr> -->
            <tr>
                <td id="colshipping">Shipping Method</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                <select id="shipping" name="shipping">
                    <option value="empty"></option>
                    <option value="USPS Express Mail">USPS Express Mail</option>
                    <option value="USPS Priority Mail">USPS Priority Mail</option>
                    <option value="DHL">DHL</option>
                    <option value="FedEx">FedEx</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fee" onblur="totals()" readonly></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="coldis">Discount</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input onchange="totals()" type="text" name="discount" id="discount" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required> %</td>
                <td><input type="text" onchange="totals()" id="amount" name="amount" readonly></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="coltotal" colspan="3">Total</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="totalPrice" id="totprice" readonly></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is whenever I fill-in the information in "form.jsp", "clientdetails.jsp" opens and shows me the details I entered except the list element, it keeps showing as empty. I'm not sure how to be able to connect between the item class and client class to be able to display the `Item1` instance in list. They told me that maybe I should do some modifications in `setItem(Item item)` method by how? 
Please any hint or advice might help me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In below method,

```
public void setItem(Item item) {
         list.add(this.item);
        }
```

Why are you doing `list.add(this.item);` ? shouldn't it be `list.add(item);`?

Change it to `list.add(item);` .

Comment: I tried doing so still not working..so I've put system.out.println("set item") statement inside the setItem method didnt see anything printed so it seems the server is not entering this method but i really dont know why

Comment: on your form.jsp, which line is supposed to call setter method `setItem(Item item)`?

Comment: that's the problem..there's nothing on form.jsp..in form.jsp:

 <td id="item">Item1</td>
                <td><input onblur="findTotal(1)" class="item" type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></td>
                <td><input onblur="findTotal(1)" class="item" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" name="price" id="price" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></td>
                <td><input onblur="totals()" class="item" type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly></td>

Comment: in this code above the user should fill the information and hence an item instance will be created, afterwards i want this instance to be added to the arraylist in client code

Comment: automatic tie up between an `<INPUT>` field and a useBean bean field happens only if name matches. Read a good article for usebean tag. Also, I am not sure about your usebean tags being used in clientdetails.jsp, I think, that should be in form.jsp

Comment: i think the main problem is in this line of code:

<td>List</td>
    <td><jsp:getProperty property="list" name="userinfo"/></td>

even when i insert <jsp:setProperty property="item" name="userinfo"/> to this code before the getProperty tag, i still cant access the setItem method. what could be the problem for that?

Comment: I guess the only way to answer you now is to try running your code. Provide full code and any scripts , xmls etc so I can set up your code in my machine.